# Material design expandable textfield width 100%

Tags: css, material-design

I'm trying to expand `md-textfield` on full width of `outer-table` element. However, it is not expanding correctly when I set `width: 100%`, the part of it goes belong the right side of a screen, and it's size has some problems.  I'm not giving `outer-table` exact width, since it should change depending on the device. Could somebody please give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong, here's what I've done at the moment.

```css
.outer-table {
  width: 100%
}

.table-header {
  position: relative;
  left: 9px;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-header  div.mdl-textfield {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: auto;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>mdl textarea</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer-table">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield full-width">
        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="expando1">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </label>
        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder full-width">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input full-width" type="text" id="expando1">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="expando1">Expandable text field</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updated after Brian's answer**

I want label element to stick on the right side, and on click expand to the left.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. it looks like in your demo everything works as you wanted, no?
what else is missing for you?

Answer (score 1):

Change this css:

```
.table-header  div.mdl-textfield {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: auto;
}
```

To this css:

```
.table-header  div.mdl-textfield {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      z-index: 9999;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Label sticks to the left side in this case, but I want it to be on the right.

Answer (score 0):

you just interchange location of the `<label>` and the `<div></div>`

```
<div class="table-header">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield full-width">

        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder full-width">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input full-width" type="text" id="expando1">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="expando1">Expandable text field</label>
        </div>
        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="expando1">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```